# Using SASS for loop to define variable color

Tags: css, loops, for-loop, sass

So I have some colors defined like this:

```
$blue_1     : #ecf5f9;
$blue_2     : #cfe5ef;
$blue_3     : #b1d5e6;
```

Now I want to automatically create  .blue_{number} classes for every color. So far I got:

```
@for $i from 1 through 12{
    .blue_#{$i}{
        color: $blue_#{$i};
    }   
}
```

But the ´color:$blue_#{$i}´ doesnt work. 
How can I reference to the variable in another way?! Im stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

[Source for the function nth](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/Sass/Script/Functions.html#nth-instance_method)

**SCSS**

```
$colors : #ecf5f9 #cfe5ef #b1d5e6;
@for $i from 1 through 3 {
  h1.blue-#{$i}
    {
      background-color : nth($colors, $i)  
     }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<h1 class="blue-1">blue one</h1>
<h1 class="blue-2">blue two</h1>
<h1 class="blue-3">blue three</h1>
```

**DEMO**

See [demo](http://codepen.io/anpsmn/pen/CBsgz)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a for loop, like this :

```
$blue_1     : #ecf5f9;
$blue_2     : #cfe5ef;
$blue_3     : #b1d5e6;

@for $i from 1 through 9 {
    @if $i == 1 {
        $bg_color: $blue1
    }
    @if $i == 2 {
        $bg_color: $blue2
    }
    .....

    .blue#{$i} 
        background-color: #{!bg_color}
}
```

That code should returns something like :

```
.blue1 {
  background-color:#ecf5f9;
}
.blue2 {
  background-color:#cfe5ef;
}
```

Comment: mh, thats not really faster than defining them manually then.. but thanks for the answer!